# nvidia-settings still present after driver uninstall

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

I just uninstalled my Nvidia drivers via command:

`./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.09.run --uninstall`

but after successful uninstall I still got `nvidia-settings` app installed.

How to uninstall nvidia completely ?

Edit: It seems that this leftover is from version:

```
/usr/bin/nvidia-settings --version

nvidia-settings:  version 346.35  (buildd@lgw01-01)  Sat Jan 17 20:13:12 UTC 2015
The NVIDIA X Server Settings tool.
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-settings`?

Comment: Yes. `aptitude search "~invidia"` gives me empty result.

Comment: It might be a typo, but take the first **i**  from `"~invidia"`

Comment: `i` stands for "installed on the system", without it it gives me a list of packages that contains string `nvidia`.

Comment: You mean `-i nvidia` @Mitch

Answer (score 1):

To remove the application only, perform `sudo apt-get remove <package>`.

Example: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*`

To remove the application and all configuration files, I suggest you perform `sudo apt-get purge <package>`.

Example: `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

Comment: There is no package installed that contains string `nvidia`.